# You can't use Airport Utility without Airport Extreme?

Tags: macos, network, macbook-pro, airport

I want to use [Airport Utility to settle wireless time limits](http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/airport_utility_setting_wireless_time_limits), it seems that I can't use Airport Utility. Is it because you can use Airport Utility only with Apple hardware like 
Airport Extreme?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Airport Utility is only for Apple's line of Airport wireless routers. This includes Airport Express, Airport Extreme, and Time Capsule. It does not support other routers.